# issues running multiple build jobs in parallel usin DIND

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a local gitlab instance using 3 runners which works fine when we have a single build job running.

Sadly, when launching 3 build jobs using `dind` in parallel, it fails with a multitude of errors:

- sometimes unable to login to docker to pull the image for cache
- sometimes the login succeeds and it fails in the build

but in both cases it complains about the certificate:

> failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker:dind CA")

Suspecting that the certificates get crashed by the other build job, we decided to separate the folder used for certificates, so it is unique to each runner, sadly the issue remains.

We have also noticed that `DOCKER_HOST="tcp://docker:2376"` the docker address is random, and many times returns the same value, which means again they are using the same resources.

I have found a guide on how to manually use a script to ensure each job is connected to its unique dind service ([HERE](https://nerdyness2012.wordpress.com/2017/10/21/concurrent-ci-pipelines-with-gitlab-ci-and-docker-in-docker-dind/)), but since the article is over 5 years old, I wonder if that is still applicable or am I doing something wrong.

Please share any advice or guidance on where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but in Jenkins by ran multiple jobs in Kubernetes. I found out that the dind image that uses the docker-cli image generates certificates each time, so you have to check if you did not mount `/certs/client` directory from the host to each builder, because in this case, the certificates will override each time when you run build job. I also got such an error `error during connect: Post "https://localhost:2376/v1.24/auth": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "docker:dind CA")`. In Kubernetes, I fixed it using pod anti-affinity preventing the scheduled two Jenkins pods on the same node:

```
affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: jenkins
                operator: In
                values:
                  - slave
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that dind break isolation, i.e. in the recommended setup all service containers mount the same /cert folder from the host: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled-in-the-docker-executor

As the dind image also seems to recreate the certificates whenever it starts, you get a conflict when running multiple jobs in parallel (i.e. by setting `concurrent = 5` in `config.toml`).

I have not found a way to make sure that the runner/service pair share a common volume which does not conflict with other concurrent runner/service pairs.

In my case, I have turned off TLS in `gitlab-ci.yml`, which solves the issue.

```
variables:

  # When you use the dind service, you must instruct Docker to talk with
  # the daemon started inside of the service. The daemon is available
  # with a network connection instead of the default
  # /var/run/docker.sock socket. Docker 19.03 does this automatically
  # by setting the DOCKER_HOST in
  # https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/d45051476babc297257df490d22cbd806f1b11e4/19.03/docker-entrypoint.sh#L23-L29
  #
  # The 'docker' hostname is the alias of the service container as described at
  # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services.
  #
  # Specify to Docker where to create the certificates. Docker
  # creates them automatically on boot, and creates
  # `/certs/client` to share between the service and job
  # container, thanks to volume mount from config.toml
  # DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```